# Bootstrap typeahead not working in MVC 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-typeahead

in my mvc project iam trying to implement the  autocomplete But it is not working (typehead) i done everything right but can't get it. below is my code . can any one help

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#Search").typeahead({
        source: function (query, process) {
            var countries = [];
            map = {};

            // This is going to make an HTTP post request to the controller
            return $.post('/Registration/GetPossibleLocations', { query: query }, function (data) {

                // Loop through and push to the array
                $.each(data, function (i, country) {
                    map[country.Name] = country;
                    countries.push(country.Name);
                });

                // Process the details
                process(countries);
            });
        },
        updater: function (item) {
            var selectedShortCode = map[item].ShortCode;

            // Set the text to our selected id
            $("#details").text("Selected : " + selectedShortCode);
            return item;
        }
    });

});
```

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript">     </script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div>
    <input type="text" id="Search" data-provide="typeahead" placeholder="Country" autocomplete="off" />    
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you specify what does not working mean? Do you get the response for your ajax call? Are there any elements in your `countries` variable?

Comment: not even typeahead calling the controller it stuck nothing happened no error no data

Comment: There is a notice on the [typeahed.js Github site](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js): Note: both bloodhound.js and typeahead.jquery.js have a dependency on jQuery 1.9+. You are using 1.8.3. Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: not working even changing to 1.10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `typeahead()` waits at least two arguments. The first argument is an options array and then you can define multiple datasets. The `source` must be defined in a dataset.

See the usage at: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#usage

As the documentations says, the `source` has to compute the suggestion set (i.e. an **array of JavaScript objects**) for query. You are passing an array of strings. 
In addition to this, you have to set the `displayKey` too.

The `source` will be executed first time if you write something into the text field.

I've made a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/dtengeri/EhJvB/

Your code should look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Notice the first empty object. You can specify options in it.
  $("#Search").typeahead({}, {
      displayKey: 'Name',
      source: function (query, process) {
          var countries = [];
          map = {};

          // This is going to make an HTTP post request to the controller
          return $.post('/Registration/GetPossibleLocations', { query: query }, function (data) {

              // Loop through and push to the array
              $.each(data, function (i, country) {
                  map[country.Name] = country;
                  // You have to create an array of JS objects. 
                  // Typeahead will use the displayKey to fetch data from the object.
                  countries.push({'Name': country.Name});
              });

              // Process the details
              process(countries);
          });
      },
      ...        
  });

});
```

Comment: when i kept alert below  map = {} alert is not firing i checked for the js error but it shows nothing

Comment: I have updated the post. You have to type something into the text field first, to fire the `source` callback.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use the bloodhound integration for getting my data source.  This is an example on how I am using it:

Bundles:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/layoutScriptsBundle").Include(
            "~/_js/_lib/jquery/jquery-{version}.js",
            "~/_js/_lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.js",
            "~/_js/_lib/typeahead.js/typeahead.bundle.js",
            "~/_js/_lib/handlebars.js/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css/libs/layoutStylesBundle").Include(
            "~/_css/_lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.css",
            "~/_css/_lib/typeahead.js/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css"));
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    window.siteNS = window.siteNS || {};
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        siteNS.typeaheadRemoteUrl = '@Url.ActionFor((ExampleController c) => c.GetTypeaheadData(null))?q=%QUERY';

        var myTypeaheadData = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: function (d) {
                return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value);
            },
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            remote: {
                url: siteNS.typeaheadRemoteUrl,
                rateLimitWait: 250,
                ajax: { cache: false }
            }
        });

        myTypeaheadData.initialize();

        $('#myTypeahead').typeahead({
            autoselect: true,
            highlight: true,
            hint: true,
            minLength: 1
        }, {
            source: myTypeaheadData.ttAdapter(),
            name: 'myTypeaheadDatasetName',
            displayKey: 'ItemName',
            templates: {
                empty: '',
                footer: '',
                header: '',
                suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<p>{{ItemName}} - {{ItemID}}</p>')
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Search/Autocomplete</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8 myTypeaheadContainer">
        <input id="myTypeahead" type="text" class="form-control">
        <span class="help-block">Using typeahead.js</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
please remove autocomplete="off" from tag  


    <div>
    <input type="text" id="Search" data-provide="typeahead" placeholder="Country" />    
    </div>
```

Comment: not worked the problem is i don't know whether post call is firing or not when i kept alert below map={} it shows nothing